# Foursquare API results is different

Tags: ios, xcode, api, location, foursquare

I am using this url to query the foursquare webserver through my iOS app:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=%f,%f&radius=4000&intent=checkin&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&v=20140328
```

I get the results around me but I do not get the venue where I am standing at the moment.

Any suggestions?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In my use of this call, I have had great results. One thing I see in the Foursquare documentation for this call's 'radius' parameter is the following:

Radius: Limit results to venues within this many meters of the specified location. Defaults to a city-wide area. Only valid for requests with intent=browse, or requests with intent=checkin **and** categoryId or query...

It looks like you could either drop the radius parameter in your request, or add the additional categoryId or query to get the right results. Hope that helps.

Comment: As you said I have to use the radius parameter with one those you mention. Im using intent=checkin. Also radius parameter is crucial for my app.

Comment: @Camus From your in the original post, I didn't see a categoryId or query with the intent parameter. Have you tried adding one of those? You have to have one of those along with the intent parameter. It would look something like: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=%f,%f&radius=4000&intent=checkin&categoryId=1234567890&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&v=20140328

Comment: Ugh. Sorry for the bad grammar in that first sentence. Editing error that I just noticed. :(

Comment: I will try query because categoryID doesn't make sense for my app.

Comment: @Camus please vote for my answer if it solved your problem. :)